# SQL syntax error when setting default value for uuid

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, uuid

I have this MYSQL query and it says I have a syntax error on line 22, the one with

```
external_id             binary(16) default unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', '')) not null
```

and I don't understand what's the problem here, can you help me? Thanks

```
create table transfer
(//other fields 
  external_id             binary(16) default unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', '')) not null,
  constraint uidx_transfer_external_id
  unique (external_id),
//other constraints
);
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, remove all stuff that doesn't matter.

Comment: The value for the DEFAULT clause must be a constant.... this mean that can't be a calculated  value as in your code .. .. you cau use trigger if you need some conversion

Comment: Which version of `mysql` do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use function in default value. Instead you can Use Triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_mytable
  BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.external_id = uuid();
```

Comment: Make note that, you might need an update trigger as well

Answer (score 0):

Wrap default value expression into parenthesis.

```
create table transfer
( -- other fields 
  external_id binary(16) default (unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', ''))) not null,
  constraint uidx_transfer_external_id
  unique (external_id)
  -- other constraints
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8ca958492159cc0a76773c4f8580a24)

PS. MySQL version 8.0.13 or above needed.